# Returning a Pandas DataFrame Index as a String

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to return the index of my DataFrame as a string.  I am using this command`p_h = peak_hour_df.index.astype(str).str.zfill(4)` It is not working, I am getting this result: `Index(['1645'], dtype='object', name`  I need it to return the string `'1645'`  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi There, please provide a [mcve] of your dataset in a format we can copy into our text editors.

Comment: `1645  47.0  14.0  186.0  53.0  12.0  33.0  19.0  891.0  64.0  160.0  743.0  431.0  2653.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short:**

do `p_h = list(peak_hour_df.index.astype(str).str.zfill(4))`. This will return a list and then you can index it.

**In more detail:**

When you do `peak_hour_df.index.astype(str)`, as you see, the `dtype` is already an `object` (string), so that job is done. *Note this is the type of the contents; not of the object itself.* Also I am removing `.str.zfill(4)` as this is additional and does not change the nature of the problem or the retuning type.

Then the type of the whole objet you are returning is `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`. You can check this like so: `type(peak_hour_df.index.astype(str))`. If you want to return a single value from it in type `str` (e.g. the first value), then you can either index the pandas object directly like so:

`peak_hour_df.index.astype(str)[0]`

or (as I show above) you can covert to list and then index that list (for some reason, most people find it more intuitive):

1. `peak_hour_df.index.astype(str).to_list()[0]`
2. `list(peak_hour_df.index.astype(str))[0]`

Comment: Thank you! Thank you for the explanation as well.

Comment: Let me bother you again.  How do you index the pandas object itself to return the string?

Comment: Updated in answer.